# Android - How to get JSON array in Child

Tags: android, json, android-volley, gson

I'm beginner in Android Studio, and I am a bit difficult to parse json data in Android, so I want to ask question about get or parsing JSON Child Array.

This is my Code :

```
public void resSuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) 
                       { progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
try {
token = response.getString("token");
JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("all_airport");
for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("airport");
    for (int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
        BandaraDataSet bds = new BandaraDataSet();
        idDep = object.getString("country_id");
        bds.setId(object.getString("id"));
        bds.setAirport_name(object.getString("airport_name"));
        bds.setAirport_code(object.getString("airport_code"));
        bds.setCountry_name(object.getString("country_name"));
        bds.setCountry_id(object.getString("country_id"));
        bds.setLocation_name(object.getString("location_name"));
        list.add(bds);
    }
}
bandaraAdapter = new BandaraAdapter(ActivityPesawat.this, list);
bandaraAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listBandara.setAdapter(bandaraAdapter);
} catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And This is my Json

```
{
    "all_airport":{
        "airport":[
                {
                "airport_name":"Mali",
                "airport_code":"ARD",
                "location_name":"Alor Island",
                "country_id":"id",
                "country_name":"Indonesia"
                },
                {
                "airport_name":"Pattimura",
                "airport_code":"AMQ",
                "location_name":"Ambon",
                "country_id":"id",
                "country_name":"Indonesia"
                },
                {
                "airport_name":"Tanjung Api",
                "airport_code":"VPM",
                "location_name":"Ampana",
                "country_id":"id",
                "country_name":"Indonesia"
                }
            ]
        },
    "token":"ab4f5e12e794ab09d49526bc75cf0a0139d9d849",
    "login":"false"
}
```

so my problem when Parse Json is null in Android, please help anyone..

Comment: Android Studio is a piece of software, not a programming language.

Comment: oh ya sorry i mean java language and im develope in android studio

Comment: what value you trying to obtain, so I can write you and example on how to parse/get it?

Comment: Thanks for response, first, I want to get the token object, then I want to get the contents of the array from the airport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are handling the `JSONObject` as if it were a `JSONArray`. Try this code:

```
public void resSuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) { 
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    try {
        token = response.getString("token");
        JSONObject airports = response.getJSONObject("all_airport");

        JSONArray airportArray = airports.getJSONArray("airport");
        for (int j = 0; j < airportArray.length(); j++) {
            BandaraDataSet bds = new BandaraDataSet();
            JSONObject object = airportArray.getJSONObject(j);
            idDep = object.getString("country_id");
            bds.setId(object.getString("id"));
            bds.setAirport_name(object.getString("airport_name"));
            bds.setAirport_code(object.getString("airport_code"));
            bds.setCountry_name(object.getString("country_name"));
            bds.setCountry_id(object.getString("country_id"));
            bds.setLocation_name(object.getString("location_name"));
            list.add(bds);
        }

        bandaraAdapter = new BandaraAdapter(ActivityPesawat.this, list);
        bandaraAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listBandara.setAdapter(bandaraAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should proper json parsing or you can use Gson(library) for json parsing. You just need to have proper Model(Bean) classes. And then parsing will be too easy.

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

Create below Model/Bean classes

```
import java.io.Serializable;

//Response.java

public class Response implements Serializable {

    AllAirPort all_airport;

    public AllAirPort getAll_airport() {
        return all_airport;
    }

    public void setAll_airport(AllAirPort all_airport) {
        this.all_airport = all_airport;
    }
}

//AllAirPort.java

public class AllAirPort implements Serializable{

    ArrayList<AirportModel> airport;

    public ArrayList<AirportModel> getAirport() {
        return airport;
    }

    public void setAirport(ArrayList<AirportModel> airport) {
        this.airport = airport;
    }
}

    //AirportModel.java

    public class AirportModel implements Serializable {

        String airport_name;
        String airport_code;


  String location_name;
    String country_id;
    String country_name;

    public String getAirport_name() {
        return airport_name;
    }

    public void setAirport_name(String airport_name) {
        this.airport_name = airport_name;
    }

    public String getAirport_code() {
        return airport_code;
    }

    public void setAirport_code(String airport_code) {
        this.airport_code = airport_code;
    }

    public String getLocation_name() {
        return location_name;
    }

    public void setLocation_name(String location_name) {
        this.location_name = location_name;
    }

    public String getCountry_id() {
        return country_id;
    }

    public void setCountry_id(String country_id) {
        this.country_id = country_id;
    }

    public String getCountry_name() {
        return country_name;
    }

    public void setCountry_name(String country_name) {
        this.country_name = country_name;
    }
}
```

Response responseObject = new Gson().fromJson(yourstringResponse, Response.class);

now you can start getting data from responseObject.

Comment: yes please explain for me, i have a model class (BandaraDataSet), and i use Volley library, but is null when parsing,

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh : at the time of your post, best is : `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`.  `compile` is deprecated, and the lib is at 2.8.2.

Comment: can i parsing with volley? 
I'm not used to using Gson

Comment: @DayatSan, don't hasitate using gson. Its very useful library. I use Retrofit in place of volley. And with retrofit I use Gson. And if you are android developer then on some day you would have to use Gson.

Comment: @DayatSan I have edited my answer to explain me. You can ask me back if any doubt.

Comment: oh oke i will try, can you give me example for this

Comment: https://gitlab.com/arshassija/customtoolbar.git
Above is my gitlab repository. You can clone or download and run in android studio 3.+
If any doubt, you can get back to me. :)